# Contact content provider observer not working stable in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

**I am using a content provider to get all contact and using contact observer to check when this contact has changed, but it not working good**

```
 @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

        Log.e("MAS_CHECK", uri + "");
        deliverSelfNotifications();

        dataBaseAdapter = new DataBaseAdapter(context);
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Dtmf app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        counter = counter + 1;
        boolean ExitFromApp = preferences.getBoolean("ExitFromApp", false);
        if (counter == 1) {
            Log.e("OTD_CHANGE", "there is change");
            if (!ExitFromApp) {
                final Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("OTD_CHANGE", "Waiting update to be stable");
                        try {
                            sleep(60000);
                            Log.e("OTD_CHANGE", "update start .. loading new data");
                            if (dataBaseAdapter.DeletAllItem()) {
                                ToolsUtils.GetContacts(context);
                            }

                            //--------------------------to restart app ----------------
                            editor.putBoolean("OTD_CHANGE", true);
                            editor.commit();
                            counter = 0;
                            Log.e("OTD_CHANGE", "update finish");
                            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(i);

                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();


            } else if (ExitFromApp) {
                counter = 0;
                editor.putBoolean("THERE_IS_UPDATE", true);
                editor.commit();
            }


        }

    }
```

**so how I can make it work every time and stable, this is the code 
when change detected it should delete the old contact in the database then re-adding new data **

Comment: `but it not working good` - you need to specify more information to get help, what exactly is not working? also the code you posted is a very generic ContentObserver, show your code

Comment: it is don't work when there is a lot of change, like if the number and photo and name was changed it is not work

Comment: Alternatively you can control `ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION` column.

Answer (score 0):

checking your code it seems there might be an issue with your `counter` field, not sure it behaves as you expect it to.

I would suggest to remove all your code from the `onChange` callback, and just add a log so you can check when and how it is being called by database changes manually.

Once you better understand how it works, and can start to restore your code, I would suggest to not use that `counter == 1` line.